# Find out GKE Calico policy?

Tags: networking, google-kubernetes-engine, calico, gke-networking

I have GKE cluster running with Version - 1.19.9-gke.1900 and trying to find out what type of Calcio policy is being used? I read through articles, calico provides different policy and below are the one's.

- VPC Native Calico with host-local IPAM
- GCP netd with Calico and host-local IPAM
- calico overlay with Calico IPAM

For my GKE cluster - how will I be able to find which above calico policy is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use [calicoctl](https://docs.projectcalico.org/reference/installation/api) , and, as per their [usage reference](https://docs.projectcalico.org/reference/calicoctl/overview)

```
  calicoctl get policy
```

Will list all policy in default output format. It worked for me with a cluster I had previously that used Calico.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try and get back